# Site IP redirect doesn't work after redirecting site to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

I am using .htaccess to redirect everything on my site to https. For example http://example.se redirects to https://www.example.se. Everything seems to be working, except the site ip 111.111.111.111 now redirects to https://www.111.111.111.111 instead of to the site https://www.example.se.

This is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.se/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

# redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.se [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.se/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the code, but now the redirect doens't work on subpages. For example http://example.se/subpage/ redirects to https://www.example.se instead of https://www.example.se/subpage/

Comment: just made an edit, use `RewriteRule backreferences` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However I have a sub catalogue where I have some problems combinig this with my present code.

`RewriteEngine On
# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.se/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

# redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.se [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.se/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

Options -Indexes

RewriteRule (.*)/ event.php?event=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/odds/events/$1$2/ [L,R=301]`